# Prove that $\frac{\Gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)} \leq \frac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Is it possible to prove that

$$\frac{\Gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)} \leq \frac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$$

where $\Gamma(n,n) = \int_n^\infty t^{n-1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d} t$ is the upper incomplete gamma function.

Equivalently, this inequality may be written in terms of Poisson distribution as

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^j}{j!}\mathrm{e}^{-n} \leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(n+1)^j}{j!}\mathrm{e}^{-(n+1)}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

which gives an interesting relation and bounds to distributions of Poisson variates.

I wonder in which way it is best to approach it.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDoe, the problem is that while the range of the integral shrinks, the term inside the integrals grows. So it is not clear how the recurrence relation of the Gamma function helps in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral inequality is equivalent to: $$\int_{n+1}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt\geq n\int_{n}^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

After doing the change of variables $t\to t-1$ in the first integral, it turns to :$$e\int_{n}^{\infty}(t-1)^ne^{-t}dt\geq n\int_{n}^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

But this is immediate if we remember $$e(t-1)^n >\dfrac{t^n}{(t-1)^n}\cdot (t-1)^n 
 = t^n\geq nt^{n-1},$$, when $t\geq n.$

**EDIT:** Original solution was wrong, so I provide a new solution.

Observe that $f(t) = t^ne^{-t}$ is decreasing on the interval $[n, \infty)$ as its derivative $f'(t) = t^{n-1}e^{-n}(t-n)$ is negative. Therefore, $$\dfrac{n^n}{e^n} = \int_{n}^{n+1}n^ne^{-n}dt\geq\int_n^{n+1}t^ne^{-t}dt = \int_n^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt - \int_{n+1}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt.$$

But this is equivalent to: $$\int_{n+1}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt\geq\int_{n}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt-\dfrac{n^n}{e^n} = n\int_{n}^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt,$$
where the latter is simply an application of integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you @dezdichado, your solution is very elegant and neat.

Comment: @sefi no problem. glad it helped

Comment: @dezdichando, I think that there's a typo in your answer. When changing variables $s  \to (t-1)$, then the term inside the integral becomes $(s+1)^n$, and not $(s-1)^n$, unless I am missing something ? Clearly, this changes the rest of the answer as well.

Comment: @sefi, I see. I'll try to fix it this afternoon.

Comment: @sefi, see the update.

Comment: @dezdichando, wonderful !