# How can I prove this sequence is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My problem is how to prove 
$$\frac{1+2}{1}  > \frac{1+3+\frac{3^2}{2!}}{1+2} > \frac{1+4+\frac{4^2}{2!}+\frac{4^3}{3!}}{1+3+\frac{3^2}{2!}}>\cdots $$

i am sure that the sequence is decreasing as limit exp(1).

**However, the reason why the sequence is decreasing is not evident.**

Thanks if you consider this issue and make me relief.

Comment: It looks like the numerator is $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}$ and the denominator is $a_{n-1}$. Then, the inequality you're trying to show can be written as $$\frac{a_2}{a_1} > \frac{a_3}{a_2} > \frac{a_4}{a_3} > \cdots$$

Comment: Yeah. i did it,  And i tried to show that a_i is log concave function but i failed it

Comment: Have you proven that the limit of the sequence $\{a_n/a_{n-1}\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ is $e$?

Comment: um.. actually, i think that the inf limit is e since (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!)> (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!+(N-1)^(N-1)/(N-1)) -> exp(N)/exp(N-1)=exp(1) as n-> infty

Comment: um.. actually, i think that the inf limit is e since (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!)> (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!+(N-1)^‌​(N-1)/(N-1)) -> exp(N)/exp(N-1)=exp(1) as n-> infty

Comment: If the sequence is decreasing and positive, then it has a limit (which is also its liminf). I'm not sure I follow your logic, though. The numerator looks like a truncation of the Taylor series of $e^N$, sure, but what would justify replacing it with $e^N$, particularly since $N$ is increasing? You've said nothing about the rate of convergence of this Taylor series. In this particular case, your intuition is correct, but this is not enough to prove that the limit is $e$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry,  I agreed your idea. I showed this sequence has inf limit as exp(1), not limit. Regretfully,  the issue i want to solve is it is decreasing function.

Comment: How did you show that the liminf is $e$?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, since this  (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!)> (1+N+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!/(1+N-1+...+(N-1)^(N-2)/(N-2)!+(N-1)^‌​‌​(N-1)/(N-1)) is accomplished and the number of temrs in denominator and nominator is same, so as n-> inf, it goes to exp(N)/exp(N-1)=exp(1)

Comment: As I said, this is not sufficient for a proof! You need some bound on the rate of convergence to make sure that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}$ actually approaches $e^n$. Namely, you need to bound the error term with respect to $e^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each term of your "decreasing" sequence is of the form: $$a_n = \dfrac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{n\Gamma(n,n)}\cdot e,$$
where $\Gamma(n,n) = \int_{n}^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt,$ the upper incomplete Gamma function. Therefore, it is equivalent to show that: $$\Gamma(n+1,n+1)\Gamma(n-1,n-1)\leq\dfrac{n}{n-1}\Gamma(n,n)\Gamma(n,n).$$

Then, the solution given to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353983/prove-that-frac-gamman-n-gamman-leq-frac-gamman1-n1-gamman1/2354041#2354041) question will help you finish the proof. Especially, you would need to modify the argument using integrals in the above answer.

I will write up a proof in a day or two if you cannot figure out the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I had changed the form as you mentioned earlier. However, This form have to be differentiated by both component inside the gamma function. Thus the form has a problem to dealing since its differentiation is tricky and thus simpler form does not appear by my mehod..

Comment: dezdichado, great approach (+1)! I'd love to see the proof  of $\Gamma(n+1,n+1)\Gamma(n-1,n-1)\leq\dfrac{n}{n-1}\Gamma(n,n)\Gamma(n,n)$ which you announced.